# The binary of negative integer number

Tags: number-representation, binary, number-bases

I have a question about the binary of negative integer number in Mathematica.

In most implementations, negative signed integers are stored in what is called two's complement. The other major way of storing negative signed numbers is called one's complement.

The two's complement of an N-bit number x is defined as 2^N - x. For example, the two's complement of 8-bit 1 is 2^8 - 1, or 1111 1111. The two's complement of 8-bit 8 is 2^8 - 8, which in binary is 1111 1000. This can also be calculated by flipping the bits of x and adding one. For example:

```
 1 = 0000 0001
~1 = 1111 1110
-1 = ~1 + 1 = 1111 1111

 21 = 0001 0101
~21 = 1110 1010
-21 = 1110 1011

 128 = 1000 0000
~128 = 0111 1111
-128 = 1000 0000
```

They can also be calculated as:

```
-1   = 2^8 - 1   = 255 = 1111 1111
-21  = 2^8 - 21  = 234 = 1110 1010
-128 = 2^8 - 128 = 128 = 1000 0000
```

These results are exactly identical to the results calculated in C language. However, when using Mathematica (I use Mathematica 11.1.0), the results are quite different:

```
BaseForm[-1, 2]   = -1
BaseForm[-21, 2]  = -10101
BaseForm[-128, 2] = -1000 0000
```

My question is: How to get the right results using Mathematica? Am I use the WRONG command?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: *Mathematica* assumes an infinite two's complement, since there is otherwise no notion of finite bits; see e.g. the docs for `BitNot[]`. You can use `Mod[]` if you wish to simulate a finite amount of bits that spill over.

Comment: Another note: when you post the same question on another place like [Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1196827), it is common courtesy to include a link to the other post, so that you don't waste other folks' time.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you for your explanation and nice reminder. I read the document and found there is no implementation of finite two's complement. I have to write it by myself. This is my code:

Answer (score 1):

I am not expert and I am mostly posting this for future me but here is how I implement 2's complement in Mathematica

```
twosComplement[x_, n_] := 
 UnitBox@IntegerDigits[x, 2, n] // FromDigits[#, 2] & // 
    Plus[#, 1] & // IntegerDigits[#, 2] & // PadLeft[#, n] &
```

I've seen other places on this site that claim to show 2's complement (can't seem to find them now) but they are actually calculating 1's complement. Or if they calculate using the definition correctly, the MSB bits are not 1's like they should be. This accounts for that. Also retains the array length when the complement has only 0's in its prefix.

Comment: Why not simply `tc[n_Integer, bits_Integer] := BaseForm[Mod[n, 2^bits], 2]`?

Comment: twos complement of an $n$-bit binary number $N$ is defined by $2^n-N$ for $N \neq 0$ and as $0$ for $N=0$.

Comment: guess I should add that $1$'s complement is $(2^n -1)-N$ and so the `Plus[#,1]&` in the formula is because 2's complement is achieved from 1's complement through $((2^n -1) - N)+1$

Comment: `tc[n,bits]` gives you the twos complement representation of `n` for word size `bits`. Apparently you want the twos complement representation of `-n`, so just use `tc[-n,bits]`.

Comment: Either we are in disagreement over the definition of what 2's complement means or my evaluation of your function is coming out differently than yours. For example computing `tc[3,4]` gives the same output as `BaseForm[3,2]` which is `11` and in my understanding of 2's complement this should be `1101`

Comment: `1101` is the 4 bit twos complement representation of the decimal integer -3. But positive integers have twos complement representation, too. Twos complement would be be pretty useless if it couldn't represent positive numbers! What's the 4 bit twos complement representation of the decimal integer `3`?

Comment: `1101`... by definition `(2^4 - 1) - 3 + 1 // BaseForm[#, 2] &` which results in `1101` recall the twos complement is by definition $2^n-N=(2^n-1)-N+1$.

Comment: what definition are you using?

Comment: The definition is the one that the OP apparently wanted, where `BaseForm[_,2]` of a **negative number** would result in the twos complement representation of the number. You're confusing the *process* of twos complement negation with the representation of a number in twos complement, so you have **positive** numbers in making **negative** numbers out.

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying. Thank you for clarifying a long held misconception!